# How can I concatenate two lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
to_do_list = ["studying", "coding"]

Times = [3, 4] #per hour
```

I want to be like this:

```
["studying", 3, "coding", 4]
```

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: It seems like you want to *interleave*, not just concatenate.

Comment: I worry that this is an XY problem and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62026607/3058609 this answer is actually correct. OP: do you want a flat list of data, or do you want to assign those values (`3` and `4`) to those keys (`studying` and `coding`)

Answer (score 1):

There are dictionaries in Python, which match two things with each other:

is this what you are looking for, or are you trying to automate this combining two lists
        thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
print(thisdict)

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I think you're on the right track. Try teaching OP how to turn `list_of_keys` and `list_of_values` into `combined_dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is when you add one list onto the end of the other:

```
>>> to_do_list + Times
['studying', 'coding', 3, 4]
```

But you don't want that; you want to have them alternate!  The `zip` function is a nice way of doing that:

```
>>> [t for t in zip(to_do_list, Times)]
[('studying', 3), ('coding', 4)]
>>> [i for t in zip(to_do_list, Times) for i in t]
['studying', 3, 'coding', 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-interleave-multiple-lists-of-same-length/, which shares the following.

```
# initializing lists  
test_list1 = [1, 4, 5] 
test_list2 = [3, 8, 9] 

# printing original lists 
print ("Original list 1 : " + str(test_list1)) 
print ("Original list 2 : " + str(test_list2)) 

# using list slicing 
# to interleave lists 
res = test_list1 + test_list2 
res[::2] = test_list1 
res[1::2] = test_list2 

# printing result 
print ("The interleaved list is : " + str(res))
```

For your program, you could do this:

```
>>> to_do_list = ["studying", "coding"]
>>> times=[3,4]
>>> res = to_do_list + times #combine lists
>>> res[::2] = to_do_list #every other element starting at 0
>>> res[1::2] = times #every other element starting at 1
>>> print(res)
['studying', 3, 'coding', 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solutions are probably to use zip :

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]

list(zip(list1,list2))
```

Or some list comprehension :

```
[sub_list[i] for i in range(len(list2)) for sub_list in [list1, list2]]
```

Output :

```
[1,3,2,4]
```

For other solutions : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-merge-two-lists-alternatively/

Comment: this is better than `list(zip(list1, list2))`?

Comment: Pretty much the same actually

Comment: My timeit results in 50% slower performance from that nested list comp. `401 nsec per loop` from zip and `681 nsec per loop` from the list comp

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is when you add one list onto the end of the other:

```
>>> to_do_list + Times
['studying', 'coding', 3, 4]
```

But you don't want that; you want to have them alternate!  The `zip` function is a nice way of doing that.  When you `zip` two lists together, you get a single iterable of tuples that "zip" the lists together:

```
>>> [t for t in zip(to_do_list, Times)]
[('studying', 3), ('coding', 4)]
```

To take the elements out of those tuples and put them into a single list, add another comprehension (i.e. do something like `for i in t` for each `t` you got out of the `zip`):

```
>>> [i for t in zip(to_do_list, Times) for i in t]
['studying', 3, 'coding', 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be various way to do this.

If the task you wanna do is '*to put elements from each list alternately to one list*', the most intuitive way is to use for loop.

Assuming two list have same length,

```python
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

list_out = []
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    list_out.append(list_1[i])
    list_out.append(list_2[i])
```

Or if you want to do it more simply, try below:

```python
list_out = sum([[a, b] for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)], [])
```

(Actually the code above can be separated to two lines:

```python
zipped = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)] # using list comprehension and zip function
# zipped = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd'], [5, 'e']]

list_out = sum(zipped, [])  # concatenate all list elements in 'zipped'
```